# Check if all flags were set (no flags blank)

Tags: go, go-flag

How do I make sure every flag argument was set from the command line? I would like to do this without checking each flag name specifically, and would like to instead check all flags dynamically.

Here is my code, `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "flag"
)

func main() {
    x := flag.String("x", "", "x flag")
    y := flag.String("y", "", "y flag")
    flag.Parse()
}
```

I run it, for example, like this: `go run main.go -x hello`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved using the [`VisitAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#VisitAll) function.

> VisitAll visits the command-line flags in lexicographical order, calling fn for each. It visits all flags, even those not set.

Sample code (add after `flag.Parse()`):

```
flag.VisitAll(func (f *flag.Flag) {
    if f.Value.String()=="" {
        fmt.Println(f.Name, "not set!")
    }
})
```